# In Xcode 6.1, iPhone 6 plus, iPad slider black screen

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

In Xcode 6.1 when i load the iPhone 6plus simulator along with the huge iPad simulators that all take up the full screen there is a scroll slider in the simulator. When i scroll the simulator a little to the right there is about a quarter of an inch black screen that covers the part that slides. When i did work in Xcode 5.1.1 for this app and iPad simulator loaded full screen it didn't have a scroll slider and it didn't have a black screen for that little part. However, now when i load the same iPad simulator in Xcode 6.1 there is that slider and the quarter of an inch black screen. Inside the storyboard the UIImageView is placed 414 width by 736 height covering the full storyboard so that's why I don't understand.Is that 1/4 inch black screen after scroll supposed to be there or does it mean my background UIImageView is not big enough to fit the entire simulator even though my UIImageView fits the entire storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal scrolling not working is a bug in the iOS Simulator in Xcode 6.1.  The only workaround is to decrease your window zoom such that the contents fit in the entire window (thus making it so you don't need to scroll).

Comment: Since you work on Apple device simulators i'll take your word for it. But since there are so many bugs on Xcode 6.1, maybe it should have stayed in beta a few months longer. Lots of issues with simulator. (Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, Code=146) error happens for no reason quite often.    I also wonder who's bright idea it was to make the iPhone 6+ simulators and iPad simulators to have 50% scale be the smaller yet covers the entire screen and there's a scroller. Had to make it just that much more difficult for the developers, eh?

Comment: There are no reports of your code=146 issue.  Please file a radar.